# String.format doesn't have an effect on a String

Tags: java, android, string

In the following code `timeToDisplay.format` seems to have no effect on the `timeToDisplay` `String`. `tw.setText(timeToDisplay)` displays milliseconds instead of expected MM:SS. I've rebuilded the project with no joy.

code:

```
 TextView tw = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textView_time);

            long millis = intent.getLongExtra("stamp", 0L);

            String timeToDisplay = String.valueOf(millis);
            timeToDisplay.format("%d min, %d sec",
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) -
                            TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));

            tw.setText(timeToDisplay);
```

Comment: This boils down to **Read The Friendly Manual**. Your title is 100% accurate.

Comment: @chrylis provided the proper answer.  format is a static method, so `String.format(` should be used.  `timeToDisplay.format(` is syntactically correct but is misleading and discouraged.

Comment: @Glenn Lane The answer have been accepted already and I'm not going to change it. Your downvoting the question and all of the answers won't change this either...

Comment: @soulreaver I haven't upvoted/downvoted... I've only deleted my own answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Strings are immutable, you have to reassign it in this way:

```
timeToDisplay = timeToDisplay.format("%d min, %d sec",
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) -
                        TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));
```

That means that the format method cant change `timeToDisplay` it only returns a new string which is formatted.

Answer (score 3):

Java strings are immutable. You have to assign the result back to a variable:

```
timeToDisplay = String.format(...);
```

In your case, you don't need to turn `millis` into a string at all; the formatter just needs the numbers that you're calculating for it.

Answer (score 0):

calling `timeToDisplay.format()` will NOT change your actual `timeToDisplay` reference.  However, it will return the new string.  Add this to your code:

```
String formattedTime = timeToDisplay.format("%d min, %d sec",
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) -
                        TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));
```

Then, use `formattedTime` in your `setText`

Answer (score 0):

strings are **immutable**. try:

```
timeToDisplay = timeToDisplay.format("%d min, %d sec",
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis),
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) -
    TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tw.setText(timeToDisplay.format("%d min, %d sec",
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis))));
```

Alternatively, you can assign the value of `timeToDisplay.format("%d min, %d sec",
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis))));` to a variable and pass that to tw.setText().